# Realizar consulta muchos a muchos laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo las siguientes tablas: 
La tabla de *operations* sirve de vinculación entre las otras dos.

Necesito realizar una consulta para imprimir todos los datos de la tabla *operations*, pero en vez de mostrar los *id* de los usuarios, necesito el nombre. Y en vez de la *id* del tipo de operación, necesito el *name*.

Además también necesito imprimir el `created_at`.

Así tengo armada la relación en el *model* del `operation_types`:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

Así tengo armada la relación en el *model* del *user*:

```
public function operationstype()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(OperationType::class);
    }
```

Esta es la consulta que intento hacer, dentro del `operationscontroller`, pero no funciona:

```
return Operation::all()->map(function ($operation) {
            return [
                'id' => $operation->id,
                'operationtype' => $operation->operationstype->name,
                'user' =>$operation->user->name,
                'created' =>$operation->create_at                
            ]; 
        })->toArray();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y tienes un modelo Operation con las relaciones a User y OperationType? Que es lo que no funciona? Te da algún error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de *eager loading* para hacer una carga ambiciosa de los usuarios con 
sus tipos de operaciones,

Tu consulta debería ser de esta forma:

```
$data = User::with('operationstype')->get();
```

Ahora si solo quieres aquellos usuarios que si tienen algún tipo de operación asociado entonces has uso del método `has` así:

```
$data = User::has('operationstype')->with('operationstype')->get();
```

Por otro lado tu tabla *pivote* no sigue las convenciones de Laravel que espera tenga los
2 nombres de las otras 2 tablas que la alimentan en orden alfabético así que deberías
pasar el nombre de la misma como segundo argumento en tus 2 métodos `belongsToMany` así:

Modelo *operation_types.php*

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'operations');
}
```

Modelo *User.php*

```
public function operationstype()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(OperationType::class, 'operations');
}
```

Comment: osea lo que quiero son todos los registros de la tabla operations. pero en vez de que salga el user->id quiero el user->name que se obtiene atravez del user->id, y en vez del operationtype->id quiero el operationtype->name que se obtiene a travez del operationtype->id. no se si se me entiende.

Answer (score 0):

asi quedaron los modelos:

user:

```
public function operationstype()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OperationType::class, 'operation_type_id', 'id');
    }
```

operationtypes:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

operations:

```
public function operationstype()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OperationType::class, 'operation_type_id', 'id');
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

esta es la consulta en el controlador:

```
public function index()
    {
        $operation= Operation::with('user')->with('operationstype')->get();

        return $operation->map(function ($operations) {
        return [
            'id' => $operations->id,
            'operationtype' => $operations->operationstype->name,
            'user' =>$operations->user->name,
            'created' =>$operations->created_at                
            ]; 
        })->toArray();

    }
```